# Cutting power to IC using MOSFET fails

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, integrated-circuit, control

The aim of the circuit is to enable/disable power to an IC (`U2`) using a transistor (`Q1`) to enable/disable ground, controlled by an MCU (`U1`). However, when the ground is disconnected, it does not shut off the IC. I.e. `U2` is behaving as it would if it was powered normally.

If the Rds of `Q1` is measured (when power is applied to the board), it is low when the transistor is enabled (a few milliohms), but when `Q1` is disabled, Rds is higher, but much lower than I expected (a little less than an ohm).

There are more inputs to `U2` from `U1` and these are all set to `HIGH`, in case there were any leaks that could cause a ground connection.

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

[image: Circuit diagram]

Components

- U1: Atmel ATxmega32E5
- U2: Laird BL600-SA
- Q1 & D1: [TI csd16301q2](http://www.ti.com/product/csd16301q2)

Comment: A proper schematic where we see what is connected where and information on how it is driven and what voltages are used would be a good for a start. This would help understanding things like, who is pulling down the gate of Q1 ...

Comment: You should look into using a high side switch (N Channel FET with charge pump) that's designed to do this. Try searching for power distribution switches. The device you've chosen is made for power applications like motor controllers.

Comment: @michaelyoyo Thanks for your comment. Could you explain in broad terms why these are a better choice, or what makes the current solution bad?

Comment: In general circuits don't like their ground to be disconnected like that. If you disconnect ANY supply rail, input signals can still put a voltage on the supply via the ESD protection diodes. It is MUCH BETTER to use the enable or power down function of the module. That's why they it is there, it is designed for that. Expect trouble if you try to do things like in your schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More likely than not, your device is finding a ground connection via its internal protection diodes and another pin that's connected to ground. Without a ground reference of its own, that pin appears to be negative from U2's point of view, and thus current flows through the ESD diode and out the pin, completing the circuit.

Comment: Would this be fixed by deploying a high side switch that @michaelyoyo suggested? E.g. [TPS2560](http://www.ti.com/product/tps2560?qgpn=tps2560)?

Comment: @user2735120 No; even with both rails disconnected, your IC can source 'parasitic' power from other pins via protection diodes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering. Final question; do you have any recommendation on how to disable power to ICs? The goal is to reduce power consumption and the IC has no enable functionality. (Truth with modification in this case)

Comment: @user2735120 There's not really a good general way to do it, unless the IC has only output pins, or you can also disconnect all the inputs. If it's an MCU, you can program in your own low power disable mode. What is "truth with modification"?

Comment: So grounding or pulling all inputs high is not sufficient? (In conjunction with ground/VCC disabling/enabling) The BL600 in this case can actually be loaded with software to enter power-down modes, but I was hoping not to, and there are other ICs on the board where this is not possible.

Comment: If all the inputs are either high or low, and the opposite supply is disconnected then there's no way for a circuit to be formed, so yes, it will disable it. If you can load firmware to actually provide a power down mode, that seems like a much better idea. Bear in mind that just because a pin is designated as 'output' doesn't mean it doesn't have protection diodes, so there's still the potential for current flow.